# .Net web client fails downloading after 2 GB from S3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I'm using the web client object to download a file like so:

```
strm = Client.OpenRead(url);
strm.ReadTimeout = 30000;

bool bFirst = true;
while ((read = strm.Read(buf, 0, 2000)) > 0)
{
    fout.Write(buf, 0, read);
}
```

Where the url points to an S3 bucket.  In some cases the download fails with a timeout at exactly 2 GB.  Is this a network issue, or is there something I could change in the code?

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What is `fout`? How are you declaring it? What is the failure signature?

Comment: I know IE has a 2GB download limit, does anyone know if that's true with the WebClient control too?

Comment: 2gb is very suspicious, as it's the maximum amount that can be represented by a (signed) 32-bit int. If your code or the API uses 'int' to represent the data size, this is likely to be the culprit.

Answer (score 6):

I believe WebClient will read the file into memory, and you're probably running into process size limitations.

What you'll want to use is [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile%28VS.80%29.aspx)

I believe this will work better for you!

Comment: +1 Spot on - although perhaps DownloadFileAsync would be nicer as you get chunked event notifications for free with that.

Comment: Yea progress bars tend to be more polite when you're downloading 2 gigs, eh? :)

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.  Pretty sure it's network related.  Thanks though.